# Booting host system with systemd-nspawn

Tags: systemd, container

I've been messing around with systemd-nspawn and overlayfs and been having a lot of fun. I successfully setup a few containers to play with.

I would like to boot a copy of my host system (Ubuntu 17.10 daily). When I run
`systemd-nspawn -D / -xb` or even just `systemd-nspawn -D / -x` the cursor just sits there blinking. No messages, no login, no errors, nothing. Why wont it boot? Does it have something to do with my system being a full graphical system? Is there a way I can see more details about what it's doing?

Edit: I've discovered the problem. `systemd-nspawn` creates a directory `/.#machine.d9a72c79cc95b034` to store the temporary system (I assume?) but since it creates the directory in the same directory it's copying it copies the new directory ... then copies that new directory and it continues until my disk is full. I end up with a directory structure something like `.#machine.d9a72c79cc95b034/.#machine.d9a72c79cc95b034/.#machine.d9a72c79cc95b034/....` hundreds of folders deep. How do I break the loop?

`systemd-nspawn -D / -xb` is one of the examples in the manpages. Weird that they would include a use case it can't handle.

Comment: Since documentation seems to cover a broken case, I recommend filing a bug at: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/ Either there's a bug in the code or docs, or the documentation could be improved.

Comment: what file system you'r using? ext4 gave error. they say we need btrfs , I added this as a feature request here https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13192

Comment: here is the answer I got : xfs and ext4 filesystems dont have a built-in snapshot feature so it cant be added. You need ( and should ) use btrfs if you want or need snapshot capabilities.